# Align the width of the entrys with the column captions

Tags: python, tkinter, datatable, size

I have created a table which consists of column captions (surname, first name, ..) and entries. Since the table has several rows I added a scrollbar to the right side of the table.

The following problem:
The width of the entry fields does not match the width of the column captions. As a result, only 3 instead of 5 columns are displayed. Of course you can change the width of the individual entries manually. But the result does not look very nice. Instead, the widths of the entries of each column should be aligned with the width of the column captions.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to implement this for the following minimal example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Name").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(root, text = "Vorname").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Label(root, text = "Land").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
Label(root, text = "Stadt").grid(row = 0, column = 3)
Label(root, text = "Adresse").grid(row = 0, column = 4)

container = Frame(root)
canvas = Canvas(container, height = 190)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for i in range(20): # number of rows
    for j in range(5): # number of columns
        Entry(scrollable_frame).grid(row = i + 1  , column = j)

container.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 5)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: They didn't in the same parent.For sure they couldn't align.Try to use `ttk.Treeview`.It can also do want you want to do.

Comment: Is there no other way ? I tried to write the labels in the same parent. It still does not work

Comment: Do you want to show all of them or make a xscrollbar?

Comment: Yes i want to display all columns

Comment: You just need to put all the `Label` in the `scrollable_frame`.And make your canvas wider.